# Can anyone write me sql query for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not a expert query writer . Scratching my head over this one . Can anyone help me out for this ?

Table tbF

```
 RecordId      MarketId

    101            1  
    102            1
    201            2
    301            3
```

Table tbSB

```
   MarketId          BMId

    1            3
    1            5
    2            1       
    2            2
    2            3
    2            4
    2            5
    3            1
```

Table tbFM

```
RecordId    BMId

101            3
102            3
102            5
201            1
201            3
201            4
```

Now I want a output as

```
   Record Id   MarketId BMId     Active 
     101        1       3          true
     101        1       5          false
     102        1       3          true
     102        1       5          true
     201        2       1          true
     201        2       2          false
     201        2       3          true
     201        2       4          true
     201        2       5          false
     301        3       1          false
```

Active column -->

If the record id present is mapped to the particular BMId its true else false
RecordId belongs to a market . --> Table tbF
Each Market has certain no of BMId mapped for it -->tbSB
Each Recordid has certain no of BMId mapped for it -->tbFM

for each record if the BMid is present in tbFM then active is true
else if the BMId is mapped for records market and not for record then for that record Active is false

Comment: Can you explain active : true/false

Comment: Where do you want the information for the `Active` field to come from?

Comment: can you tell me, what is active,you are nowhere specified this column in your tables

Comment: Exactly. This is a horrible naming convention. Please provide a better one or at least tell us about foreign keys (relations) between these tables. And what about active?

Comment: I think `Active` is defined by existence in the `tbFM` table but, I'd like to see some query attempt before providing an answer.

Comment: We are not your workers,you are not even worried for specify the full details about your table and their relationship.

Comment: **Show us some effort on your side!** - [what have **you** tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: My apologies for incomplete data provided . I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  f.RecordId
  , f.MId
  , s.BMId
  , Active = CASE 
    WHEN m.RecordID is null THEN 'false'
    ELSE 'true'
    END
FROM tbF f
INNER JOIN tbSB s ON f.MId = S.MId
LEFT JOIN tbFM m ON m.RecordId = f.RecordID AND m.BMId = s.BMId
```

I've taken Active to be determined by the existance within the tbFM table - since the expected output shown in the question matches that logic.